# Dedication to late father

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I am writing a blurb about my photography book that I have dedicated to my late father.

I am looking for a word to complete the sentence.

Here is the sentence:

"I dedicated the book to my late father in … that he could see these places with me."

Comment: What meaning are you hoping to have this convey?

Comment: You mean something like "I wish that he could have seen these places with me", yes?

Comment: Some answers depend on your religious views.  Do you believe that the spirit of your (late) father is (still) capable of seeing these places via your book?  Or do you believe that his death prevents him from seeing these places with you?

Comment: @Jasper raises a key point. Moreover, which meaning you wish to convey will affect the rest of the sentence, particularly the verb tenses in the latter part. For example: _I dedicate this book to my late father, wishing he could have seen these places with me_ (that's wistfulness, wishing he could have been there). Or: _I dedicate this book to my late father, hoping he has seen these places with me_ (that's expressing a hope that your father has been with you in spirit as you took your pictures).

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you for the religious perspective - something I did not consider.

Answer (score 2):

Answered in comments:

> ...which meaning you wish to convey will affect the rest of the sentence, particularly the verb tenses in the latter part. For example: I dedicate this book to my late father, wishing he could have seen these places with me (that's wistfulness, wishing he could have been there). Or: I dedicate this book to my late father, hoping he has seen these places with me (that's expressing a hope that your father has been with you in spirit as you took your pictures). –  [J.R.♦](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r) [Feb 23 2015](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51381/dedication-to-late-father#comment95571_51381)